# Gentile driving for you on Yom Tov

Tags: halacha, gentiles, yom-tov, vehicles-transportation

May a Jew be driven somewhere by a Gentile on Yom Tov? If so, what are the conditions which would allow this to be possible?

Comment: [Pikuach nefesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pikuach_nefesh#Shabbat_and_holidays)?